# How to configure PHP builid

Tags: php, linux, gettext

I'm attempting to add the gettext() extension to the PHP build, the [installation instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gettext.installation.php) are not very clear:

```
To include GNU gettext support in your PHP build you   
must add the option --with-gettext[=DIR] where DIR is the    
gettext install directory, defaults to /usr/local.
```

1. Where do i place this option, and in which file? (I have never configured PHP before)
2. Is Apache restart required? If so, how long does it take and what are the dangers?

I have not installed gettext myself, it looks to be preinstalled on my system:

```
# rpm -qi gettext    
Name        : gettext                      Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 0.17                         Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 16.el6                       Build Date: Thu 11 Nov 2010 04:06:25 AM EST
Install Date: Tue 30 Jul 2013 03:03:04 PM EDT
```

Comment: You probably can find a prepacked php_gettext via rpm. If you wanna build PHP from source (that's what the manual note is about) then just run `./configure --with-gettext` within the PHP source tree.

Comment: @mario How do i search prepackaged via rpm?

Answer (score 0):

The gettext extension is installed by default, but not its PHP bindings. Install package [php-gettext](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=php-gettext) to add those to your system. The package manager will handle all other bindings for you, and probably even restart Apache for you. On a normal system in a normal situation that takes less than a second, and your users won't notice anything since Apache gracefully waits for existing requests to finish when shutting down.

Ignore the install notes in the PHP manual when not running a self-compiled version of PHP - on systems like Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS etc. the package manager will handle most common tasks like this for you in a safer way.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it looks like I'm missing a few dependencies: `lib64php5_common5 >= 3:5.4.6 is needed by php-gettext-3:5.4.6-1.x86_64` `libintl.so.8()(64bit) is needed by php-gettext-3:5.4.6-1.x86_64` Do i have to search them myself? Will this overwrite anything important?

Comment: I don't know how CentOS specifically works, but there should be a way to install a package automatically including all its dependencies. It's unlikely that it'll break anything, but possible. You should be taking a CentOS tutorial though if you don't know basic stuff like this about a server you apparently have root access to.

Answer (score 0):

The comment in the instructions is directed towards compiling from source.

Like Niels wrote, package manager should do the job and take care of all missing dependencies. Since your system is CentOS try this:

```
yum install php-gettext
```

Answer (score 0):

I come to this question with the [php-build](https://github.com/CHH/phpenv) tool. In case to compile with php-build tool and would like to add the custom configuration, you can configure it in `/usr/local/share/php-build`. (Ubuntu), it may in another directory up to your platform.

Go there and edit file `default_configure_options` and put any custom configurations as you wishes.

ex.

`--with-gettext=/usr/bin`